# NetworkManager requests authentication despite having credentials stored

Tags: wireless-networking, networkmanager

### The Problem

I have a wifi connection that works for the most part. Sometimes it disconnects and `nm-applet` shows a popup asking for the wifi-password, but the password is already filled in and I just need to confirm it for it to connect again.

During the time which it disconnects until I confirm the credentials I have no internet connection.

### What I have discovered

I ran `sudo journalctl -u NetworkManager` and looked through the logs around the most recent disconnection. I do not know what the issue could be but the latest warning lines up somewhat with the issue timewise.

###### journal entries

```
<warn>  [1698165031.6878] device (wlp8s0): no secrets: No agents were available for this request.
<info>  [1698165031.6879] device (wlp8s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1698165031.6883] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
<info>  [1698165032.2078] device (wlp8s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to C6:1C:DC:4D:05:1E (scanning)
<warn>  [1698165032.7150] device (wlp8s0): Activation: failed for connection '<Network Name>'
<info>  [1698165032.7151] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
<info>  [1698165032.7151] device (p2p-dev-wlp8s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
<info>  [1698165032.7152] device (wlp8s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1698165032.7353] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
<info>  [1698165032.7353] device (p2p-dev-wlp8s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
```

It continues to scan until this

```
<info>  [1698170938.1459] device (wlp8s0): Activation: starting connection '<Network Name>' (bd5926db-140d-4bf6-82be-f063b3591774)
<info>  [1698170938.1460] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="bd5926db-140d-4bf6-82be-f063b3591774" name="<Network Name>" pid=1237 uid=1000 result="success"
<info>  [1698170938.1461] device (wlp8s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1698170938.1464] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
<info>  [1698170938.6359] device (wlp8s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 50:3E:AA:74:18:C3 (preserve)
<info>  [1698170939.1030] device (wlp8s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1698170939.1033] device (wlp8s0): Activation: (wifi) access point '<Network Name>' has security, but secrets are required.
<info>  [1698170939.1034] device (wlp8s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1698170939.1037] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
<info>  [1698170939.1038] device (p2p-dev-wlp8s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
<info>  [1698170939.1044] device (wlp8s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1698170939.1046] device (wlp8s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1698170939.1049] device (wlp8s0): Activation: (wifi) connection '<Network Name>' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
<info>  [1698170939.1050] Config: added 'ssid' value '<Network Name>'
<info>  [1698170939.1050] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
<info>  [1698170939.1052] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
<info>  [1698170939.1053] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
<info>  [1698170939.1053] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
<info>  [1698170939.1054] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
```

> secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.

Why is it then prompting me (the user) for credentials?

Any fixes to either problem? (preventing disconnect entirely / reconnecting automatically)